# Comprehensive guide to manipulating axes in idl

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am trying to have 4 plots in the same window using

```
    !p.multi=[0,2,2]
    !p.position=[0.11,0.5,0.5,0.9] ...some code
    !p.position=[0.5,0.5,0.9,0.9] ...some code
    !p.position=[0.11,0.1,0.5,0.5] ...some code
    !p.position=[0.5,0.1,0.9,0.5] ...some code
```

The position of the plots is perfect (see graph [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/missfroguk/5883550203/)) but

a/ I would like to remove the scale on the x axis in the top 2 plots and have it at the top of the top plots rather than at the bottom.

b/ I would like to have the y axis on the right of the 2 plots on the right rather than on their left.

I have managed to do this kind of plot in the past but after hours playing with the [xy]style and axis commands. Part of the problem is that I can't find a comprehensive guide on the internet which would simple break down each style such that

> xstyle = 1 ;definition
>
> xstyle = 2 ; definition

...you get the jist of it.

Would somebody be able to refer me to a good guide on how to manipulate axes in idl so that I don't have to guess the styles each time I have to plot. If not, would somebody be able to break down the style and axis options / commands very simply on stack overflow? I doubt I'm the only one stumbling upon this problem time and time again...?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to draw an axis on the "opposite side", you need to suppress the axis (i.e., [XY]AXIS=4) and then make the axis yourself in the correct location with the AXIS command.

The online help has definitions for the values of [XSTYLE](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/Graphics_Keywords.html#wp332116) and the options to [AXIS](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/AXIS.html).